# Adding items to a list in flutter and dart

Tags: flutter, dart

The code below is working well. But I want, String `match` to be from an input field, then when the user types the first letter, items that contain that one letter to be added to a list, then when the user enters the second letter the items that contain only both letters to remain in the list... and if the user enters the third, fouth, fifth and onwards, items that contain those letter to remain in the list.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scroll_to_index/scroll_to_index.dart';

class HighLight extends StatefulWidget {
  const HighLight({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HighLightState createState() => _HighLightState();
}

class _HighLightState extends State<HighLight> {

  AutoScrollController autoController;

  List<String> list = ['Good morning friends', 'How are you doing today', 'morning is the best time to exercise', 'I dont know why he doesnt morning want us to use one branch', 'I am sure he is willing to help', 'I think he is just playing game', 'All eyes on me now', 'Ill try my best to be morning the best'];

  String match = 'morning';

  List<int> itemList = [];

  int counter = -1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    autoController = new AutoScrollController();

    autoController = AutoScrollController(
      viewportBoundaryGetter: () =>
          Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
          onPressed: () =>  _prevCounter(),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _nextCounter,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          controller: autoController,
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){


            for(var item in list){
              if(item.contains(match)) {
                itemList.add(list.indexOf(item));
              }}

            return AutoScrollTag(
                key: ValueKey(index),
                controller: autoController,
                index: index,
                highlightColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text('${list[index]}'),
                ));


          }),
    );
  }

  _nextCounter(){
    if(itemList.isNotEmpty ){
      setState(() {
        counter++;
      });
      return _scrollToCounter();
    }
  }

  _prevCounter(){
    if(itemList.isNotEmpty){
      setState(() {
        counter--;
      });
      return _scrollToCounter();

    }
  }

  Future _scrollToCounter() async{
    print(itemList);
    print(counter);

    var index = itemList.elementAt(counter);

    print("index $index");

    await autoController.scrollToIndex(index, preferPosition: AutoScrollPosition.middle);

    autoController.highlight(index);

  }
}
```

Comment: use `List.where` method, for example: `list.where((item) => item.contains(match)).toList()`

Comment: do you want to select one by one or all at once

Comment: btw why dont you add "filter out as you type" functionality as every other apps do when searching the list? it would be much more easier to implement it than scrolling to matching items

Comment: @pskink you mean, add all items to ListItem, then if item does not contain match the remove from the list.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh. any can do, provided it does not highlight an item that does not contain match

Comment: @pskink let me try your first comment

Comment: i mean, why dont you filter out your `ListView`? for example if your list has 8 items and 3 of them match then show only those three matching items

Comment: Yes, but it did not build successfully. Actually, I noticed that the problem is the ItemList[]. It is growing... so I am trying to find a way to remain with duplicates; Just an example of what is happening, the first time, the list will add the index of the item that contains match as [1,3,4] then the second time [1,3,4,1,3] and so on.

Comment: Build... and it is working perfectly, but now my question was adding the index of those items that contain a match to the list... Please see the problem I am facing in the above comment

Comment: I want to use `scroll_to_index` package to scroll and highlight an item that contains match. I don't want to cut out non matching items exactly.

Comment: That is perfect. Thanks alot

Comment: still, this is bad UX example: the right approach is to filter out non matching items like every apps are doing

Comment: Yeah, Btw, speaking of UX, I would love to discuss with you about optimizing performance and UI freezing. I should create a question for this? or there is other ways I can reach you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TextEditingController with listen to handle match cases.

```dart
class HighLight extends StatefulWidget {
  const HighLight({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HighLightState createState() => _HighLightState();
}

class _HighLightState extends State<HighLight> {
  late AutoScrollController autoController;

  List<String> list = [
    'Good morning friends',
    'How are you doing today',
    'morning is the best time to exercise',
    'I dont know why he doesnt morning want us to use one branch',
    'I am sure he is willing to help',
    'I think he is just playing game',
    'All eyes on me now',
    'Ill try my best to be morning the best'
  ];

  String match = '';

  List<int> itemList = [];

  int counter = -1;

  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    autoController = AutoScrollController();

    autoController = AutoScrollController(
      viewportBoundaryGetter: () =>
          Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom),
    );

    controller.addListener(() async {
      match = controller.text.trim();
      if (match.isEmpty) {
        return;
      }
      itemList.clear(); // clear before new selection
      for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].contains(match)) {
          itemList.add(i);
        }
      }
      setState(() {});

      print(itemList);

      /// scroll to 1st match item
      await autoController.scrollToIndex(itemList.first,
          preferPosition: AutoScrollPosition.middle);

      // for (final i in itemList) {
      autoController.highlight(itemList.first);
      // }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
          onPressed: () => _prevCounter(),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _nextCounter,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          controller: autoController,
          itemCount: list.length + 1,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return index == list.length
                ? TextField(
                    controller: controller,
                  )
                : AutoScrollTag(
                    key: ValueKey(index),
                    controller: autoController,
                    index: index,
                    highlightColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text('${list[index]}'),
                    ));
          }),
    );
  }

  _nextCounter() {
    if (itemList.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        counter++;
      });
      return _scrollToCounter();
    }
  }

  _prevCounter() {
    if (itemList.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        counter--;
      });
      return _scrollToCounter();
    }
  }

  Future _scrollToCounter() async {
    print(itemList);
    print(counter);

    var index = itemList.elementAt(counter);

    print("index $index");

    await autoController.scrollToIndex(index,
        preferPosition: AutoScrollPosition.middle);

    autoController.highlight(index);
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting let me build this and see

Comment: I want a procedural flow... But synchronous...